# Cannot resolve property `paramName` in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I need to set Spring MVC interseptors to catch url parameter `language` and accordingly get data from `.properties` file. Getting error `Cannot resolve property`paramName when configuring context in `servlet-config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/pdfs" location="pdfs"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ttu.cs.controller"/>

     <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource" p:basename="messages" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <bean id="LocaleResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver" p:defaultLocale="en"/>

    <!-- Declare the Interceptor -->
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
            <property name="paramName" value="language"/>
        </bean>

    </mvc:interceptors>
</beans>
```

Comment: It means the class org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver does not have a property called 'paramName'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to use `org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor` rather than `SessionLocaleResolver`.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="language"/>
</bean>
```

This class is a `HandlerInterceptor` and does have a `paramName` property.

`SessionLocaleResolver`, on the other hand, is not.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you expect but SessionLocaleResolver doesn't have such a param. Maybe you meant locale?